# How to get the current context name using Kubernetes client

Tags: go, kubernetes-go-client

I'm trying to access the current cluster name by getting the current context name.
So I wanted to know how to get the current context name using client provided by: "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cluster name output by the `kubectl cluster-info` command is only stored in the local kubeconfig file, it is not part of an API. So, you can not get the cluster name by using the client.